# Performing math on table columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am tasked with "optimizing" a spreadsheet. I have some code that pulls data from a csv file, dumps it into a workbook and then creates a table and performs some other stuff with the data. What I am wondering is if there is a way to perform, let's say, some simple division on the table while only referencing the headers.

example:

```
Range("SurveyStaging[[Central Bandwidth Values]:[Bandwidth Values]]").Value = Range("SurveyStaging[[Central Bandwidth]:[Bandwidth]]").Value
```

Works just fine, however:

```
Range("SurveyStaging[District]").Value = Range("SurveyStaging[Central Bandwidth]").value/Range("SurveyStaging[School Bandwidth]").Value
```

Throws type mismatch.

Any idea on how to do this without having to loop through every cell in the columns?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to adapt the rows and columns for your own code, but I think this will work.

It doesn't use a loop; it manipulates the whole range at once.

```
Dim count1 As Double

count1 = 1

While Range("A" & CStr(RowNumber + count1)).Value <> ""
    DoEvents
    count1 = count1 + 1
Wend

count1 = count1 - 1
'the count is so that it takes an accurate number of rows to manipulate

Range("B2", "B" & CStr(count1)) = "=(RC[-1]/RC[-3])"
' you will have to put in whatever columns you'll be dividing with their NUMBER
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but is what I ended up using in the end. Thank you tannman357. I appreciate it.